# Python regular expression matching a multiline javascript code

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a Python regex to work when matching against text that spans multiple lines. My example is:

```
function initialize() 
{
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.800567,5.942068);
    var myOptions = 
    {
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: true, 
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var locations = [  

    ['<div CLASS="Tekst"><B>tss&nbsp;fsdf<\/B><BR>hopp <BR><\/div>', 54.538665,24.885818, 1, 'text']
    ,
    ['<div CLASS="Tekst"><\/div>', 24.465462,24.966919, 1, 'text']
    ]
```

What I want to extract is context in locations. As result I want to look like:

```
 - '<div CLASS="Tekst"><B>tss&nbsp;fsdf<\/B><BR>hopp <BR><\/div>',
   54.538665,24.885818, 1, 'text' 
 - '<div CLASS="Tekst"><\/div>', 24.465462,24.966919, 1, 'text'
```

I try regex like this:

```
regex = r"var locations =\[\[(.+?)\]\]"
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: have you tried `re.MULTILINE` or `re.DOTALL` ?

Comment: yap. Probably is somthing wrong with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello you can try this regex

```
re.findall("(<div.+)\]",toparse)
```

Comment: Thank you :) You save my life. I spend 3 hours for  doing this regex :D